# Destroy or disable Audio Listener programmatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following static camera:

```
public Camera standbyCamera;
standbyCamera = GameObject.Find("StandByCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
```

How can I disable or destroy the associated Audio Listener via code?

I've tried the following, as well as some variants, and nothing works.

**How can I disable the Audio Listener associated with a camera?**

---

[From the Unity forums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/211287/disabling-audio-listener-in-unity-3d.html):

```
standbyCamera.GetComponent (AudioListener).enabled = false;
```

> error CS0117: 'UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for 'enabled'

---

```
Destroy (standbyCamera.GetComponent (AudioListener));
```

> 119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will instead want to do:

```
Destroy(standbyCamera.GetComponent<AudioListener>());
```

It looks like you might be able to [pause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html) as well.

Or if that is not enough you could try making a child object with the audiolistener and enable/disable that child.